# finding time complexity formula of an algorithm for checking if number is prime

Tags: time-complexity

I have some difficulties in finding time complexity formula **(T(n))** of an algorithm for checking if number is prime.

Here is the function :

```
Is_prime_number (n)

   {
         if (n==1) return 0;
         if (n==2) return 1;
         if (n mod 2==0) return 0;
         for(i=2; i*i<=n; i+=2)
            if(n mod i==0)
              return 0;
         return 1;
    }
```

Now, I know there are 3 comparisons outside the loop, and therefore
**T(n)= 3 + c*sqrt(n)**, but I am not sure about the value of c in this equation.

Answer (score 0):

The main operation inside the for loop is finding the `modulo`. According to this [article](http://shoup.net/ntb/ntb-v2.pdf), for finding `a%b`, the time taken is roughly:

`O(n.log(b)` for `a=q⋅p+r` and `n=log(a)`.

So,it depends on the number of bits, a and b have and will be roughly equal to `O(log(a).log(b))`. So in this case, `c` would be equal to `O(log(a).log(b))`.